# how to make a transition from one mesh to another?

Tags: javascript, three.js, tween.js

I have mesh1 and Mesh2. Each has extrusion.

```
mesh1 ->100 vertices
mesh2 ->200 vertices
```

In my code I do the following:

```
mesh1.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
mesh1 = Mesh2;
mesh1.geometry.computeBoundingBox ();
```

and so I manage to update mesh1 (this works in my original code), but I do not want you to see any abrupt change. I want an animation while mesh1 becomes the geometry Mesh2.

I've always used the library tween.js. So for example:

```
 new TWEEN.Tween (mesh1.scale) .to ({x: 1, and 1, z 1}, 1000) .start ();
```

but I don't know how to do animation in this case.
With transition or animation, you see the changes in real time of the vertices of mesh2 to mesh1. I do not want to display any abrupt change.

Comment: What do you mean by "transition" and "animation" ?

Comment: @AndyRay with transition or animation I mean you see the changes in real time vertices of Mesh2 to mesh1. I do not want to display an abrupt change.

Comment: It would be incredibly complicated to do, and involve a lot of work, especially if your number of vertices change. This is too broad of a question to be answered on stack overflow.

Comment: @AndyRay it is impossible? or is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [updating vertices in Three.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32362161/updating-vertices-in-three-js)

Comment: This is the third question you made a copy of, for not understanding answers/comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `morphTarget` for it. You have sets of vertices with same length, but with different positions. Then you set the `morphTargetInfluences` to effect the transition from that set of vertices to another set of vertices.

This is from Threejs Geometry [documentation](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Core/Geometry)

```
.morphTargets

Array of morph targets. Each morph target is a Javascript object:
{ name: "targetName", vertices: [ new THREE.Vector3(), ... ] } Morph vertices match number and order of primary vertices.
```

This is a good [example](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_morphtargets.html). View it's source code for better understanding.